# How to get Refresh Token in spring boot using JWT

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I am doing spring security for REST API using JWT. I have already done with creating web token with expiry time and its working fine . I have set the time limit to 5 minutes . After 5 minutes, the token will get expired. This causes problem for me, so can anyone guide me how to solve this one by using refresh token, since I am very new to this concept.

Here is my code..

SpringSecurityConfiguration

```
 @Bean
 public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter() {
    JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter filter = new 
    JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new JwtSuccessHandler());
    return filter;
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority("Admin")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.headers().cacheControl();

}
```

TokenController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/token")
public class TokenController {

private JwtGenerator jwtGenerator;

public TokenController(JwtGenerator jwtGenerator) {
    this.jwtGenerator = jwtGenerator;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String generate(@RequestBody final User user) {

    return jwtGenerator.generate(user);

}
}
```

JwtGenerator

```
@Component
public class JwtGenerator { 
private Long expiration;
private String secret = "youtube";
static final String CLAIM_KEY_CREATED = "created";

public String generate(User user) {
    Claims claims = Jwts.claims()
            .setSubject(user.getFirstName());
    claims.put("password", String.valueOf(user.getPassword()));
    //claims.put("role", jwtUser.getRole());

    return Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .setExpiration(generateExpirationDate())
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "youtube")
            .compact();
}

private Date generateExpirationDate() {
    return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()  + (5 * 60 * 1000));
}
}
```

JwtAuthenticationProvider

```
@Override
protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {

    JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken = (JwtAuthenticationToken) usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
    String token = jwtAuthenticationToken.getToken();

    User user = validator.validate(token);

    if (user == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("JWT Token is incorrect");
    }
    String firstname=user.getFirstName();
    User user1=userRepository.getRoleId(firstname);
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = AuthorityUtils
            .commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(user1.getRole().getRoleName());
    return new JwtUserDetails(user.getFirstName(), user.getPassword(),
            token,
            grantedAuthorities);
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return (JwtAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass));
}
```

JwtValidator

```
@Component
public class JwtValidator {


private String secret = "youtube";

public User validate(String token) {

    User user = null;
    try {
        Claims body = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(body.getSubject());
        user.setPassword((String) body.get("password"));
        //user.setRole((String) body.get("role"));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return user;
}
```

}

I am passing username and password to get the token.Thanks in advance

Comment: do you solved ?

Comment: I would not put the password in the JWT itself. Unless you're going to encrypt it. Either way, there's no point in putting the password there since it already must be known at the source.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably need to change a little bit existing solution. You have to in general after successfull authorization return 2 JWT tokens - one 'access' JWT token used to any other authorized request to server, and the 'refresh' JWT token which is used to retrieve new 'access' JWT token when first one expired. It also means that You will need to change/modify/intercept front-end part of application to apply these rules. Good point is for me here [JWT Authentication Tutorial - An example using Spring Boot](https://svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/).

Comment: Best example ever.